# simple_salesforce python how to rewrite this using bind variables

Tags: python, simple-salesforce

```
    revenue = sf.query("SELECT Id, Name, Net_Revenue__c, Price__c, Credits__c, Gross_Revenue__c, Account__r.Name \
    FROM Revenue__c WHERE Account__r.Id = '"+accountId+"' and MonthYear__c = '"+year_month+"'" )
```

this works, but how can I convert it to use bind variables or parameters. I can do it with 1 variable but can't figure out how to have 2 bind variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on Python 3.6 or above, you can simply use an f-string:

```
revenue = sf.query(
    "SELECT Id, Name, Net_Revenue__c, Price__c, Credits__c, Gross_Revenue__c, Account__r.Name "
    f"FROM Revenue__c WHERE Account__c = '{accountId}' and MonthYear__c = '{year_month}'"
)
```

Particularly  if these values are user input, you might wish to use the newer method `format_soql` instead, as it will automatically quote values and escape nested quotes to defend against SOQL injection:

```
revenue = sf.query(
    format_soql(
        "SELECT Id, Name, Net_Revenue__c, Price__c, Credits__c, Gross_Revenue__c, Account__r.Name "
        "FROM Revenue__c WHERE Account__c = {accountId} and MonthYear__c = {year_month}",
        accountId=accountId, year_month=year_month
    )
)
```

Note that you should filter against `Account__c`, not `Account__r.Id`; it's the same data, but without attempting to traverse a relationship.

Comment: Thanks David, much appreciated.